# ng-switch condition being evaluated every digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one of two directives being rendered as a result of a `ng-switch` condition.

Even though the condition rarely changes, the condition is being evaluated every digest.

Are there any idiomatic optimizations I can apply to avoid this check and improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you two ways

First you can use one time binding this value won't change once it has been stabilized 
e.g. :`<p id="one-time-binding-example">One time binding: {{::name}}</p>`

Second way can be usage of debounce function i.e it will delay the digest cycle according to your requirement.
e.g

```
 <input ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 150 }" />
```

here time is given in milliseconds.

Other than this i don't think there is any direct way to solve this problem.